# view all data related in xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml

what i want to do is it appear all related data from selected xml file. i already declare the node path to be search which is `XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Patient/Patient/Name");`. However, my output only display the last data and not the overall data for path needed.

This is my xml file.

```
   <Patient> 
  <Patient>
    <LevelPriority>0</LevelPriority>
    <Name>w</Name>
    <Id>1</Id> 
  </Patient>      
  <Patient>
    <LevelPriority>0</LevelPriority>
    <Name>asf</Name>
    <Id>2</Id> 
  </Patient> 
  <Patient>
    <LevelPriority>0</LevelPriority>
    <Name>add</Name>
    <Id>3</Id>        
</Patient>
```

and this is my output.

[image]

what i want it to appear is:

> w
>   asf
>   add

rather than just the last data `add`.

this is my code in viewForm.

```
namespace SliceLink
{
    public partial class ViewForm : Form
    {           
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();            
            xml.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Patient/Patient/Name");            
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string name = xn.InnerText;                   
                textBox1.Text = name;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

how to make it view the for all the data required?

Comment: In the XML sample you provide you need to add an additional closing `</Patient>` element, I just copied and pasted that to try it and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You have to append the new text (`name`) to the text that is already there:

```
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string name = xn.InnerText;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + name;
}
```

Also, you might want to insert some delimiter (here: a whitespace character):

```
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string name = xn.InnerText;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + name;
}
```

Check `textBox1.Text.Length` for zero if you don't want to insert the space before the first item.